# WPF only drawing 4 images (with C# & XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to customize a digital photo frame program template I found on MSDN but I found that it only shows 4 images at the max. If I add a 5th image to the ArrayList, the entire screen goes blank.

Does anyone know what's going on and why any images after the 4th added to the ArrayList will cause the image to disappear and window to blank out?

[post edit: included full source]

C# source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace CSWPFAnimatedImage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int nextImageIndex;
    List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the images collection
        images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
        images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image2.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
        images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image3.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
        images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image4.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

        nextImageIndex = 2;
    }

    private void VisbleToInvisible_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the source of the myImage1 to the next image to be shown
        // and increase the nextImageIndex
        this.myImage1.Source = images[nextImageIndex++];

        // If the nextImageIndex exceeds the top bound of the collection,
        // get it to 0 so as to show the first image next time
        if (nextImageIndex == images.Count)
        {
            nextImageIndex = 0;
        }

        // Get the InvisibleToVisible storyboard and start it
        Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("InvisibleToVisible") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(this);

    }

    private void InvisibleToVisible_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the source of the myImage2 to the next image to be shown
        // and increase the nextImageIndex
        this.myImage2.Source = images[nextImageIndex++];

        // If the nextImageIndex exceeds the top bound of the collection,
        // get it to 0 so as to show the first image next time
        if (nextImageIndex == images.Count)
        {
            nextImageIndex = 0;
        }

        // Get the VisibleToInvisible storyboard and start it
        Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("VisibleToInvisible") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(this);
    }  

}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CSWPFAnimatedImage.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="WPF Animated Image Sample" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="VisibleToInvisible" Completed="VisbleToInvisible_Completed" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransparentStop"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="0"  Duration="0:0:2"   />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BlackStop"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="0" Duration="0:0:2"
                        />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="InvisibleToVisible" Completed="InvisibleToVisible_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransparentStop"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="1"  Duration="0:0:2"   />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BlackStop"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"   />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource  VisibleToInvisible}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid Name="grid">        
    <Image x:Name="myImage2" Source="Images/image2.jpg" />
    <Image x:Name="myImage1" Source="Images/image1.jpg">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Black" x:Name="BlackStop"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" x:Name="TransparentStop"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
</Grid> </Window>
```

Comment: The code is working fine with me

Comment: whats the size of your image?

Comment: 70 KB .jpeg. Try adding your own image. The code works with the already-existing images, but if I try and put something else in (which is what I want to do because it's a digital photo frame), the window blanks out.

Comment: I added my own 8 images. I created new project and copied the code from the link u gave. No problems for me. Also i moved the instantiation of images before InitializeComponent()

Comment: i mean images.add() things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here this works

```
images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
```

and this doesn't

```
images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\\image2jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
```

so. change it to

```
images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\\image2jpg", UriKind.Absolute)));
```

It works when you copy an image from somewhere and paste it to the Images folder of the project and add it to the image list.

Comment: I was referencing the images from my C drive. Copying + pasting to the images folder and dragging them as references in the Solution Explorer instantly fixes it. Thanks so much!

Comment: the second Uri is absolute but stated as relative. It is highly possible that the program is looking for directory D under project folder.